# How to rollback truncate data in hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

Unfortunately, I truncated a table in hive and trash got cleaned up. Is there any way to get the data back.thanks

Comment: If you have deleted trash as well, I doubt there is a way

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to recover deleted file(s) but it's not recommended and if not done properly can affect a cluster as well. Use these procedure with caution on production system

Here's step by step description to recover accidentally deleted files.

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/26181/how-to-recover-accidentally-deleted-file-in-hdfs.html